# SqsListener String index out of bounds issue

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I'm encountering a really weird problem when trying to use the `@SQSListener` annotation from the Spring Cloud module.
Here's my listener method:

```
@SqsListener(value = "myproject-dev-au-error-queue")
public void listenPhoenix(String message) throws IOException {

    logger.info(message);
 }
```

However, once I run the project, it starts reading messages from the queue and fails with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "simpleMessageListenerContainer-4" Exception in thread "simpleMessageListenerContainer-6" Exception in thread "simpleMessageListenerContainer-9" Exception in thread "simpleMessageListenerContainer-10" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessageUtils.getNumberValue(QueueMessageUtils.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessageUtils.getMessageAttributesAsMessageHeaders(QueueMessageUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessageUtils.createMessage(QueueMessageUtils.java:56)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$MessageExecutor.getMessageForExecution(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:375)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$MessageExecutor.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:336)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$SignalExecutingRunnable.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:392)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

With the problematic part being in the spring-cloud-aws-messaging module `QueueMessageUtils` class `numberType` variable assignment:

```
private static Object getNumberValue(MessageAttributeValue value) {
    String numberType = value.getDataType().substring("Number".length() + 1);

    try {
        Class<? extends Number> numberTypeClass = Class.forName(numberType).asSubclass(Number.class);
        return NumberUtils.parseNumber(value.getStringValue(), numberTypeClass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException var3) {
        throw new MessagingException(String.format("Message attribute with value '%s' and data type '%s' could not be converted into a Number because target class was not found.", value.getStringValue(), value.getDataType()), var3);
    }
}
```

Has anyone seen this before and if so is there a way to fix this?

P.S: Since I don't really care about the message attributes I wouldn't mind if they were completely ignored.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The exception in the given code is thrown from the following line.

```
String numberType = value.getDataType().substring("Number".length() + 1);
```

According to the documentation in AWS JAVA SDK,it explains how the `getDataType()` function works (See [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/MessageAttributeValue.html#getDataType--)). According to the documentation, it will return one of the following values.

- String
- Number
- Binary

> Amazon SQS supports the following logical data types: String, Number,
>   and Binary. For the Number data type, you must use StringValue.

Now, when you call `value.getDataType()`, it will return one of the above values. Assuming it's `"Number"`, you are trying to get a `substring` of it, starting from index 6 (where `"Number".length() + 1 = 6`)

But there is no such index in the String returned by `value.getDataType()`. Therefore, it will throw a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

**As a solution** for this, you can simply use the following instead of getting the substring of it.

```
String numberType = value.getDataType();
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is that this method is part of the Spring Cloud messaging module. I've raised an issue in their github repository: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/374

Comment: @DannyPetrunov Please keep us posted on any solutions. I once implemented using the AWS Java SDK and used this exact method. It worked for me. Getting the substring of it and trying to work it out, does not seem like a good practice imo

Answer (score 0):

I have also face the same issue, when publishing message with **SQS Extended Library**, it automatically added one attribute along with the message **SQSLargePayloadSize** with the datatype **Number** which is causing the problem. the exception is resolved by updating the dependency from

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-aws-messaging', version: '2.2.6.RELEASE'
```

to any latest version of awspring **spring-cloud-aws-messaging**

```
implementation group: 'io.awspring.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-aws-messaging', version: '2.4.1'
```

make sure all the package must be imported from **io.awspring.cloud**